# Convert *.mov file to *.mp4 with media source support

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, media-source

My goal is to play converted *.mp4 file with HTML5 Media Source Extension (MSE).
I made a small video with iMovie on my Mac and exported this video to *.mov file. Using ffmpeg I've converted *.mov file to fragmented *.mp4 file.
I used code from Mozilla Media Source tutorial to make simple html5 video player.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API/Transcoding_assets_for_MSE

But I couldn't get my video played with this tutorial. Other *.mp4 videos play just fine. But I have troubles with converted *.mov videos.

I've checked codec support for my video. 
On this page I've got my codec info:

http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/mp4info/

```
track #0 codec string: mp4v
track #1 codec string: mp4a.40.2
track #2 codec string: tmcd
MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="mp4v, mp4a.40.2, tmcd"'); // => false
```

I found that `tmcd` codec is not supported by MSE:

https://cconcolato.github.io/media-mime-support/

I couldn't find the way to get my video work with MSE. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -write_tmcd 0 out.mp4` to strip the timecode and try.

Comment: @Mulvya Every video I tested have different codecs. Some of them not supported by Chrome or Safari. How can I convert any video such as it will be compatible with most browsers? Is there way to convert any codec to one common codec? And which codec is preferable?

Comment: H.264 and AAC are the standard codecs, To make a fragmented MP4:  `ffmpeg -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov out.mp4` You can disable tmcd if that's an issue.